# A tricky multiple integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multiple-integral

I am to calculate this:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}dy\int\limits_{-\arccos(y)}^{\arccos(y)}e^{\sin(x)}dx$$
I noticed that $sin(x)$ is an odd function thus $e^{\sin(x)}$ is odd either but that's all. I have no further ideas how to deal with that integral.

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of integration?

Comment: Not yet. How to know when switching the order of integration can help? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: There is a theorem that says when you have multiple integrals, you $\textit{must}$ switch the order of integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the trick is to switch the order of integration.  If we rewrite the integral in the order $dxdy$, we have 
$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\cos(x)} e^{\sin(x)}\,dx\,dy
$$
Switching the order of integration is a good thing to look for if you find that the first integral is not doable.

Comment: Are you sure that integrals are in proper order? I mean the limits are linked to $x$ in the second integral and we're integrating with $dx$?

Comment: I'm sorry! Now everything is clear. Thank you very much :)